# How to retrieve all properties from Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Consider the following sample code from Microsoft:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using SP = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace Microsoft.SDK.SharePointServices.Samples
{
    class RetrieveListItems
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string siteUrl = "http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection";

            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
            SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements");

            CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='ID'/>" +
                "<Value Type='Number'>10</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>";
            ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);

            clientContext.Load(collListItem);

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (ListItem oListItem in collListItem)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ID: {0} \nTitle: {1} \nBody: {2}", oListItem.Id, oListItem["Title"], oListItem["Body"]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This assume you know very well that Title and Body are available in oListItem from SharePoint List Objects. However, any easy way to retrieve all available properties just like JSON.stringify() in javascript? thanks.

Moreover, I have tried:

```
foreach (ListItem oListItem in collListItem)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<String,String> kv in oListItem.FieldValuesAsText.FieldValues)
    {
        var value = kv.Key;
        Console.WriteLine("key=" + kv.Key + " value=" + kv.Value);
    }
}
```

But there is nothing printed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check [ListItem.FieldValuesAsText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem.fieldvaluesastext.aspx) property.

Try this:

```
namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static string FromDictionaryToJson(this Dictionary<string, string> dictionary)
        {
            var kvs = dictionary.Select(kvp => string.Format("\"{0}\":\"{1}\"", kvp.Key, string.Concat(",", kvp.Value)));
            return string.Concat("{", string.Join(",", kvs), "}");
        }

        public static Dictionary<string, string> FromJsonToDictionary(this string json)
        {
            string[] keyValueArray = json.Replace("{", string.Empty).Replace("}", string.Empty).Replace("\"", string.Empty).Split(',');
            return keyValueArray.ToDictionary(item => item.Split(':')[0], item => item.Split(':')[1]);
        }
    }
    class Program
    {   
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            using (var clientContext = new ClientContext("http://sp:12001/"))
            {
                #region MyRegion
                List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Users");                
                CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
                query.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='ID'/>" +
                 "<Value Type='Number'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>100</RowLimit><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID'/><FieldRef Name='Title'/></ViewFields></View>";

                var items = list.GetItems(query);

                clientContext.Load(items, eachItem => eachItem.Include(
                item => item.FieldValuesAsText));               
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                foreach (ListItem oListItem in items)
                {
                    var values = oListItem.FieldValuesAsText.FieldValues as Dictionary<string, string>;
                    Console.WriteLine(Extensions.FromDictionaryToJson(values));
                }
                Console.WriteLine(items.Count);
                #endregion
                Console.ReadKey();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I have tried ListItem.FieldValuesAsText.FieldValues.Count is 0 but the item does contains data.